# How to create custom progress View?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

In iphone the UIProgressView height is fixed, i need to create UIProgressView for height 40(variable height), how to write my custom code in drawRect method? i am new to Quartz drawing any samples available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used below code...
http://rlopezxl.com/2009/10/16/monotouch-drawing-custom-progress-bars/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you may not need to subclass `drawRect:`.

Presumably the images for your progress view are "stretchable" (i.e. they have fixed size left and right ends with a middle part that can be stretched)? You can create a stretchable image by loading a `UIImage`, calling [`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW4) to get an image you can assign to a `UIImageView`. Then, when you resize the `UIImageView`, the image redraws correctly automatically -- the left and right "caps" are drawn at the left and right end of the image view, and the middle part is stretched to fill the middle.

Your progress bar becomes a view that holds two `UIImageView`s as children: one for the background and one for the filled progress bar. With clever use of the `autoresizingMask`, you should only need to change the frame of the progress bar fill to update the display.